# What are the official sources of vehicles in Dark Heresy?

Tags: warhammer-40k, vehicles, dark-heresy-2e, dark-heresy-1e

The 2nd edition of the Dark Heresy RPG Core Rulebook has many pages worth of rules for vehicles. It then backs this up with the stats for a car, a bike, and a tank (technically an APC I suppose, but still). There are rules for walkers, skimmers etc, but no stats for them.

Having looked through several vaguely related rulebooks, there are more vehicle stats. None seem to be perfectly meant for use in Deathwatch v2, with issues such as the rarity stat being lacking, and potentially balance issues bringing vehicles from high powered games like Deathwatch into DH.

Has there been any official confirmation about what sources (Only War, Deathwatch, Rogue Trader, other) 'are official' for use in DH, or rules for adapting these sources to DH2?

Comment: list of all the vehicles in the v1:
http://www.40krpgtools.com/bestiary/

Comment: Since fantasy flight is not producing any more wh40kjrp we might never have official one. For fan-made list of vehicles for v2: http://www.rollforheresy.net/comment/428

Comment: I've checked both 40krpgtools.com and rollforheresy.net. The former is a compilation of item listings, but not their actual information. The latter is no longer available on the net.

Answer (score 1):

All rule books are *supposed* to be compatible with each other, or at least this is the intention. You may need to fiddle, but as far as I'm aware it should direct port. I'd have no problem running a Sentinel from *Only War* in the *Rogue Trader* game I run.

As far as "where should I go then" *Only War* has the most vehicles, or at least the "fun" ones your acolytes could reasonably expect to have access to by "borrowing" them from the Guard. *Rogue Trader* has a lot on ships and the like and I think *Deathwatch* would have things too, but it'd all be Space Marine sized.